# JQuery - Select all but last list (from multiple lists.)

Tags: jquery, xhtml, jquery-selectors

I'm wondering if this is the most elegant and efficient way of doing this?

I have multiple 'tag' lists, and through CSS, I want the tags to appear inline (display: inline) and be comma-separated.  The challenge that I'm having is to append commas to all but the last list item in each ul.tagList:

```
 <ul class="outerList">
    <li>
        <div class="innerContainer">
            <ul class="tagList">
                <li>Tag A</li>
                <li>Tag B</li>
                <li>Tag C</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="innerContainer">
            <ul class="tagList">
                <li>Tag D</li>
                <li>Tag E</li>
                <li>Tag F</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

To append commas on all the ul.tagList list items, but the last, I use:

```
 $('ul.tagList').children(':not(:last-child)').append(',');
```

and this produces:

> Tag A, Tag B, Tag C
>
> Tag D, Tag E, Tag F

Is this the best way of doing this?

Also why does *:not(:last-child)* work but not *:not(:last)* in this context?

Thanks very much for your help + explanations.

Prembo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:last` does not work in this context, because it will only match **one** element, namely the **last**.

`last-child` can match more elements, one for each parent.

Your code looks pretty fine, using [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) instead of querying with sizzle might improve performance slightly.

```
$('ul.tagList').children().not(':last-child').append(',');
```

Comment: Jquery is awesome, as well as you @jAndy :)

Answer (score 1):

This was posted a long time ago but thought it good to post for anyone else (like me) who looks at this post as a reference. I made a jsPerf for the two cases stated above plus one I added myself using .prevAll()

```
$('.tagList').children(':last-child').prevAll().css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

It is slightly faster

http://jsperf.com/all-but-last-performance